# MFC GetDC() Assertion failure - "Not a window"

Tags: c++, mfc

Goal: Draw a plot in a child window, on a static control plotScreen. The plot will somtimes be drawn from live incoming data so I am drawing to a compatible DC to reduce flickering.

Problem: The code works correctly to draw the plot to the main frame using `GetActiveWindow()` then `GetDC()`, but I cannot get the program to recognize the child window or the static control as a window.

The line that causes the assertion failure:

```
CDC *pDC = plotScreen.GetDC();
```

The creation of plotScreen:

```
plotScreen.Create("Gamma Playback", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP | BS_PUSHBUTTON | DT_CENTER, plotRect, thisParent, NULL);
```

The assertion failure:

```
ASSERT(::IsWindow(m_hWnd)); return CDC::FromHandle(::GetDC(m_hWnd)); }
```

The static is created before the GetDC is called.

Edit: the static is successfully created but destroyed. I tried using new to allocate on the heap but it is still destroyed before I can use it in a later function.

Comment: That assertion means (a) the window has not yet been created, or (b) the window has already been destroyed. If you put a break-point on the line triggering the assertion, and another on the line you claim creates the child window, you can conclude which case is happening fairly quickly. That, of course, assuming the child window is created successfully (which you never validate, as you're ignoring the result of the `Create` call).

Comment: Thank you Whoz Craig. The creation is successful because I can see the CStatic - it persists because it is a member of the class that creates the child window that hosts it. However following your advice I see that "plotScreen" is a null handle both during creation and during the Get DC(). Do you have any advice for how to obtain device context for a child window or Cstatic, or how to get the handle properly?

Comment: Your parent window's `OnCreate` is the place to invoke the child create, and that only after the base (which I assume is a `CFrameWnd`) has been invoked (usually the first thing in the `OnCreate` override). And you never mentioned it: did the `Create` of the child control return TRUE or not?

Comment: And fyi, `DT_CENTER` does not belong in the window style of your child control. That's a [`DrawText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162498(v=vs.85).aspx) format indicator; not a window style.

Comment: Yes the Create returned TRUE (non-zero). I created this CStatic manually as it is a rectangle to hold the plot in a child window, not a dialog. It is created in the OnCreate override of the child window Plot, which is a child on the main frame. Plot is created in the OnCreate of the main frame.

Comment: It's supposed to be a button? Any reason you're not using `CButton`? Just curious.  That sets using the window class for a button (which is "BUTTON", btw).

Comment: Its just a rectangle to hold the plotting area... I put it to leave a bit of a frame and to make it easier to tell it where to plot when I do... I'm really not sure of the best way - the code I am reformulating used a picture control in a dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

Solution = get a pointer for the window containing the CStatic during the OnCreate of that window. Store in a global variable. Use this pointer to get DC.

Comment: `GetDC` is generally not meant for drawing (it also needs `ReleaseDC` cleanup). Try owner draw static control https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760767(v=vs.85).aspx#owner_drawn_static_control